# Не одно совещание, на котором(ых) было решено

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: «...не одно совещание, на котором было решено» или «на которых было решено?»

Comment: проведено не одно совещание..... Употребить в единственном числе сказуемое?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что каждое совещание приближало совещающихся к принятию окончательного решения; на всех совещаниях что-то решалось, поэтому

*на котор**ых** было решено.*

Единственное число было бы возможно при указании, что вот, например, только последнее (совещание) дало плоды (привело к консенсусу), тогда

*на котор**ом** было решено.*

Ваше уточнение в  комментарии -

*Проведено не одно совещание, на которых было решено...* -

не оставляет места для единственного числа.

Comment: В реальной жизни решение могло быть принято только на одном и последнем совещании по рассматривавшемуся поводу. Конечно, это не должно приводить к единственному числу, но надо осторожнее обойтись с "которыми" ("по результатам которых" и т. п.), иначе решение окажется принятым на всех совещаниях сразу.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, вы хотите сказать, что было проведено много совещаний, на которых что-то было решено. Тогда так:

**Проведено не одно совещание, на которых было решено...**

Теоретически, можно придумать контекст, в котором будет уместно "на котором". Например:

**Было проведено не одно совещание, на котором было решено..., а два таких совещания.**

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убрать союзное слово КОТОРЫЙ во избежание неблагозвучия и использовать другую, более подходящую конструкцию, например:

***...проведено не одно совещание, в результате чего было решено...***

Если же оставить КОТОРЫЙ, то надо менять начало фразы:

***...проведено несколько совещаний, по завершении которых было решено...***